# How to properly use NSDistributedNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver to listen for lock screen events C# Mono

Tags: c#, macos, cocoa, mono

I'm trying to use NSDistributedNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver to listen for system lock events using Mono in C#. I haven't really been able to find any documentation for this or examples. So far I have the following code:

```
NSDistributedNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver((NSNotification nsn) => { Console.WriteLine("hi"); }, null, NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, null);
```

The API for AddObserver looks like the following:

```
[Export ("addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:")]
public virtual void AddObserver (NSObject observer, NSString keyPath, NSKeyValueObservingOptions options, IntPtr context);
```

Comment: The API is already obsolete, so move to alternatives please, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsdistributednotificationcenter.addobserver?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12

Comment: Thanks Lex. I found something similar in my research. Now I'm just figuring out how to use it in a console app.

Comment: @KO-DEV - were you able to figure it out? I am trying to read events through NSDistributedNotificationCenter using Xamarin.Mac.